# Wave front set of vector-valued Dirac delta distribution

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, microlocal-analysis

**Context:** I am reading a physics paper [Local Wick Polynomials and Time Ordered Products of Quantum Fields in Curved Spacetime](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0103074) which applies the notion of the wave front set to operator-valued distributions in a globally hyperbolic spacetime. In particular, the paper considers vector-valued distributions $W_n$, whose wave front set is (eq. 9)

\begin{equation}
\text{WF}(W_n)=\left\{ (x_1,k_1,\dots,x_n,k_n)\in(T^*M)^n \backslash \left\{0\right\}|k_i\in V^-_{x_i},i=1,\dots,n  \right\},
\end{equation}
where $V^\pm_{x_i}$ denotes the future/past lightcone in the tangent space of $x_i\in M$.  It is then claimed that we will get well-defined products between these $W_n$ distributions and distributions whose wave front sets are subsets of

\begin{equation}
G_n(M,g)\equiv (T^* M)^n \backslash \left(\bigcup_{x\in M} (V_x^+)^n\cup\bigcup_{x\in M} (V_x^-)^n \right),
\end{equation}
where $g$ denotes the spacetime metric.

It is then asserted that the wave front set of the distribution 
\begin{equation}
t(x_1,\dots,x_n)\equiv f(x_1)\delta (x_1,\dots,x_n) \tag{eq. 16} \label{t}
\end{equation}
is a subset of $G_n(M,g)$ because its wave front set is 
\begin{equation}
\text{WF}(t)=\left\{(x,k_1,\dots,x,k_k)\in (T^*M)^k \backslash \left\{0\right\}|\sum_i k_i =0 \right\}. \tag{*} \label{WFt}
\end{equation}

**Questions:**

1) It is not clear to me why the wave front set of \eqref{t} is given by \eqref{WFt}.  More descriptively, taking the Fourier transform of, e.g.,  $\delta(x_1,x_2)=\delta (x_1)\otimes \delta (x_2)$, I get 
\begin{equation}
\delta(e^{ix_1\cdot k_1},e^{ix_2\cdot k_2})=(e^{i0\cdot k_1},e^{i0\cdot k_2})=(1,1),
\end{equation}
which suggests to me that the wave front set of \eqref{WFt} is instead $(0,k_1,\dots,0,k_n)$ for $k_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$

2) Even if I were accept that the wave front set of \eqref{t} is given by \eqref{WFt}, it is not clear to me how the condition $\sum_i k_i=0$ implies that this wave front set is a subset of $G_n(M,g)$.  In particular, suppose $i=2$ and thus $k_1+k_2=0 \rightarrow k_1=-k_2$.  Now, if $k_1\in{V^+_x}$, then $k_2\in{V^-_x}$ which would seem to imply that this wave front set is not a subset of $G_n(M,g)$.

Comment: It seems to me that $(*)$ is the prototype of wavefront set of the diagonal delta $\delta_{\triangle}(\phi)=\int_M\phi(x,\ldots,x) d\mu_M$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(M^k)$

Comment: The way $G_n(M,g)$ (somethimes those are called microcausal functionals) is defined leaves out distributions whose wavefront set lies ENTIERLY either in $V_x^+ \times \ldots \times V_x^+$ or in $V_x^- \times \ldots \times V_x^-$, so in your example the distribution has a future directed and a past directed covector, but cannot have both future or past directed at the same time and thus is in $G_n(M,g)$.